# Posting an Array in ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How can I receive a JSON array on a POST method?

**JSON being sent**

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Lavern",
        "LastName": "Massery"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Sunny",
        "LastName": "Blazier"
    }
]
```

**My Model**

```
public class Member {
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    ....
 }
```

**My Controller**

```
[Route("api/v1/members")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class MembersController : ControllerBase {
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Member[]> Create(Member[] members) {
         ....
    }
 }
```

**The Error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied
>   values.

I'm able to successfully grab a single member (in a different controller), but when in array form, it throws the exception. I've also tried using `List's` and `ObservableCollection's`, and even a custom class to hold them, but nothing works, and the error isn't specific enough for me to know if the json, model or controller is at fault. What am I missing here?

Comment: It might be worth trying the [FromBody] attribute on your array. Also maybe post the client side code which is attempting to post to this controller along with the URL it is using. And I guess its also worth checking your routing config in case you have some unusual routing going on.

Comment: Have you tried `Create([FromBody] Member[] members)`?

Comment: It might also be worth putting a get method into this controller with no parameters just to check that the basic routing is working and narrow it down from there.

Comment: I'm just using postman for testing, https://localhost:5001/api/v1/members now, for some reason setting a breakpoint the method is getting triggered, but the array is empty.

Comment: [FromBody] seems to have fixed it... I promise i tried that earlier and it didn't work. The joys of programming.

Comment: Would have been helpful to see a screenshot of your postman request. You mentioned it’s hitting the breakpoint but the array is empty. Like people mentioned above that you should try FormBody attribute before the parameter type in the action.
Also in postman make sure you set content type to application/json.
Under the Raw tab type in your json object with the same names as the properties of member.

Comment: @bwoogie, show us how you send that array to server i.e. ajax call.